# Reset Row Number in Oracle conditionally

Tags: sql, oracle, reset, row-number, rownum

I have this record set returned , now I want to have a row number column which gets reset after every 3rd row. Can anyone help me with this? needs to be done with Oracle SQL.
Explanation below-

| data | current row number | rquired row number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Chris | 1 | 1 |
| Bryan | 2 | 2 |
| Jim | 3 | 3 |
| Davis | 4 | 1 |
| Kia | 5 | 2 |
| Jones | 6 | 3 |
| Mary | 7 | 1 |
| Carrie | 8 | 2 |
| Pearce | 9 | 3 |
| Cesar | 10 | 1 |
| Bob | 11 | 2 |

Comment: `MOD(current_row_number+2, 3)+1` Should do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [mod](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/MOD.html) the current value:

```
mod(current_row_num - 1, 3) + 1
```

So using a CTE to represent your current result set:

```
with your_result (data, current_row_num) as (
  select 'Chris', 1 from dual union all
  select 'Bryan', 2 from dual union all
  select 'Jim', 3 from dual union all
  select 'Davis', 4 from dual union all
  select 'Kia', 5 from dual union all
  select 'Jones', 6 from dual union all
  select 'Mary', 7 from dual union all
  select 'Carrie', 8 from dual union all
  select 'Pearce', 9 from dual union all
  select 'Cesar', 10 from dual union all
  select 'Bob', 11 from dual
)
select data, current_row_num, mod(current_row_num - 1, 3) + 1 as required_row_num
from your_result
order by current_row_num
```

| DATA | CURRENT_ROW_NUM | REQUIRED_ROW_NUM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Chris | 1 | 1 |
| Bryan | 2 | 2 |
| Jim | 3 | 3 |
| Davis | 4 | 1 |
| Kia | 5 | 2 |
| Jones | 6 | 3 |
| Mary | 7 | 1 |
| Carrie | 8 | 2 |
| Pearce | 9 | 3 |
| Cesar | 10 | 1 |
| Bob | 11 | 2 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=b1f8c7bf9de18d285114986047f31c31)